# "A part" or "parts"?

Tags: nouns

When you refer to a generalized part of a generalized plural noun, should I use "a part" or "parts"?

> do you have to use " city names" as "a part/parts" of " commercial addresses"?

This is the only example I could come up with using the "generalized  part of a generalized plural noun" formula, so if you have better examples, please help!

**EDIT:**

Can you help me with the example below,  where plural nouns should be used (or at least I think they should be used in this context)?

> Please use **color names** as a part/parts of **design titles**?

It sounds weird to me, but I can't pinpoint why . Am I misusing plural nouns in this case?

Comment: I don't think it would occur to native speakers to use plural *parts* in such contexts. We'd say, for example, *"Do you have to use **city name** as **part** of **a** commercial address?"*

Answer (score 1):

A city only has one name, therefore it's name is a singular object.  So when you include it in an address, the name is a single "part" of the larger collection.